# Threads and Synchronisation

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, semaphore

I am working on code. The description is as follows :
There is a professor and number of students(assumed 3 in the code). The students can ask questions and the professor will reply keeping the following in mind-

(i) only one person is speaking at a time,

(ii) each student question is answered by the professor, and

(iii) no student asks another question before the professor is done answering the previous one.

A probable output for the code can be :

```
Student 0 enters the office.
Student 1 enters the office.
Student 1 asks a question.
Professor starts to answer question for student 1.
Professor is done with answer for student 1.
Student 1 is satisfied.
Student 0 asks a question.
Professor starts to answer question for student 0.
Professor is done with answer for student 0.
Student 0 is satisfied.
Student 0 leaves the office.
Student 2 enters the office.
Student 2 asks a question.
Professor starts to answer question for student 2.
Professor is done with answer for student 2.
Student 2 is satisfied.
Student 2 leaves the office.
```

My code is attached below, I am not getting the desired output. Any help on what I am doing wrong is much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

sem_t student,professor, askQuestion,numberOfStudents;
int id=0,number=0;

void AnswerStart()
{
  printf("Professor starts to answer question for studnet %d\n",id);
  return;
}

void AnswerDone()
{
  printf("Professor is done with the answer of student %d\n",id);
  return;
}

void QuestionStart()
{
    printf("Student %d asked a question\n",id);
    return;
}

 void QuestionDone()
{
  printf("Studnet %d is stisfied\n",id);
  return;
}

void Studnet(void *a)
{
  sem_wait(&numberOfStudents);
  number++;
  printf("Student %d enters office\n",(int *)a);
  sem_post(&numberOfStudents);

  sem_wait(&askQuestion);
  id = (int *)a;
  QuestionStart();
  sem_post(&professor);
  sem_wait(&student);
  QuestionDone();
  sem_post(&askQuestion);

  sem_wait(&numberOfStudents);
  number--;
  printf("Student %d leaves office\n",(int *)a);
  sem_post(&numberOfStudents);
}

void Professor(void *a)
{
  printf("Professor is in office\n");
  while(1){
     sem_wait(&professor);
     AnswerStart();
     AnswerDone();
     sem_post(&student);
     sem_wait(&numberOfStudents);
     if(number==0)
     return;
     sem_post(&numberOfStudents);
 }

}


int main(){

sem_init(&student,0,0);
sem_init(&professor,0,0);
sem_init(&askQuestion,0,1);
sem_init(&numberOfStudents,0,1);

pthread_t studentThread[3], professorThread;
pthread_create(&professorThread,NULL,Professor,NULL);
pthread_create(&studentThread[0],NULL,Studnet,(void *)0);
pthread_create(&studentThread[1],NULL,Studnet,(void *)1);
pthread_create(&studentThread[2],NULL,Studnet,(void *)2);

pthread_join(studentThread[0],NULL);
pthread_join(studentThread[1],NULL);
pthread_join(studentThread[2],NULL);
pthread_join(professorThread,NULL);

sem_destroy(&student);
sem_destroy(&professor);
sem_destroy(&askQuestion);
sem_destroy(&numberOfStudents);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a variant of the dining philosophers problem, you might want to search for and read about it?

Comment: It would be nice to know what's wrong with your output. Or... what the output is?

Comment: I checked it on linux (after fixing void* return for thread functions and void* cast to int since 64bit) and **it works fine**. The only thing I can think of is that the program hangs since the professor loops `while(1)` and is being waited in the main. What is the problem with your output?

Comment: @ArnonZilca I am getting this output :

`Professor is in office

Student 0 enters office

Student 1 enters office

Student 2 enters office

Professor starts to answer question for studnet 0

Student 0 asked a question

Student 1 asked a question

Student 2 asked a question

Professor is done with the answer of student 2

Studnet 2 is stisfied

Studnet 2 is stisfied

Studnet 2 is stisfied

Professor starts to answer question for studnet 2

Student 0 leaves office

Student 1 leaves office

Student 2 leaves office

Professor is done with the answer of student 2`

Comment: Professor starts to answer is being displayed before student has asked the question.

Comment: @Bart Shared my output in the comment above

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add more details, like the actual output. Also please add the *expected* output.

Answer (score 1):

**Of course!** ( it took a while =] )

You're using the same `id` variable for all of your students and reading & writing it from different threads!

remove global `id` variable and instead of

```
id = (int *)a;
```

write:

```
int id = (int)a;
```

and make your print functions take an int argument as follows:

```
void QuestionStart(int id)
void QuestionDone(int id)
```

In order to keep your professor prints with the student number you can use a global variable, let's call it `currentStudent` that will be set only after acquiring the professor's semaphore.
[* I think you'll need another semaphore for splitting the professor's work from assigning that variable]

---

If there's still a problem try adding this line after each print:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

[maybe there's also a print flushing problem]

Answer (score 0):

```
given the criteria stated in the question...

a common resource is the professor    
a common resource is the office


the professor resource can have several states:

not in office
entering office
in office, doing nothing
in office listening to question
in office answering question
(optional exiting office)


each student resource can have several states:

waiting for professor to be in office, doing nothing
(transition student entering office)
student in office stating question
student in office listening to answer
(transition student exiting office)


there are criteria:

a student cannot enter office unless
--professor is in office, doing nothing

professor cannot exit office unless
--professor is in office doing nothing




the office resource can have several states:

no one in office
professor entering office
professor in office doing nothing
professor in office and student entering
professor in office and student in office
professor in office and student exiting office
professor exiting office


using the above (or develope your own)
write out a state diagram
determine when state changes are allowed for each resource
(office, student(s), professor)

It seems, to me, that the main restriction
is the state of the office
so perhaps make the state of the office
a common datum, protected with a mutex

use enum variables for the state of each resource

there is only one professor, 
-- suggest professor be handled by main()

there are several students,
-- suggest thread for each student

after writing the state diagrams 
with the transition criteria 
for each state change to the next state
The actual coding should be very simple

I would suggest using a mutex rather than a semaphore,
just to keep it simple
especially as there can be only one student 
using the resource at any one time, so no need for any counting semaphore

suggest, for any one resource, 
the states be tested using a switch statement
with each case being one state, 
and each case has the criteria for when to switch to the next state
```